# Using a combo of 2x6 batts and 2" polyiso foam as vapor barrier inside of 2x8s?

Tags: insulation, vapor-barrier

I am in need of insulating 2x8 cantilever bays, under my kitchen, accessible through my basement. I was considering pulling up the cantilever OSB and then running plastic under, then putting 2x8 (7.25") rockwool inside. This is met with a clear problem that I would need to rip up a whole lot more flooring than I would prefer.

I also happen to have a pallet of 2x6 (5.5") R-23 Rockwool. I don't need all of it to insulate my walls. That got me wondering if I could use *that* to insulate the cantilever bays in combination with a rigid board, like `RMAX Pro Select R-Matte Plus-3`. The combined thickness would be 7.5", so the rockwool would just need to squish a little bit, lowering its R value (I know), but the Rmax is also 13, so not a big deal - in combo they should be about equivalent to or exceed R-30 2x8 insulation. The board is polyiso with a foam face, and has a rating of <0.1 perms, aka vapor retarder. This would eliminate the need for a plastic vapor barrier. Seems like a win-win.

Is there anything wrong with this idea?